# Parsing the first occurrence of a word that is not precded by white space

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

**Setting**

I need to find the first occurrence of a word in some .txt file that is not preceded by white space. Here are the possible cases:

```
-- * should succed
t1 = "hello\t999\nworld\t\900"
t2 = "world\t\900\nhello\t999\n"
t3 = "world world\t\900\nhello\t999\n"

-- * should fail
t4 = "world\t\900\nhello world\t999\n"
t5 = "hello world\t999\nworld\t\900"
t6 = "world hello\t999\nworld\t\900"
```

Right now t6 is succeeding even though it should fail, because my parser will consume any character until it reaches hello. Here is my parser:

**My Solution**

```
import Control.Applicative

import Data.Attoparsec.Text.Lazy
import Data.Attoparsec.Combinator
import Data.Text hiding (foldr)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as L (Text, pack)



-- * should succed
t1 = L.pack "hello\t999\nworld\t\900"
t2 = L.pack "world\t\900\nhello\t999\n"

-- * should fail
t3 = L.pack "world\t\900\nhello world\t999\n"
t4 = L.pack "hello world\t999\nworld\t\900"
t5 = L.pack "world hello\t999\nworld\t\900"

p = occur "hello"    

---- * discard all text until word `w` occurs, and find its only field `n`
occur :: String -> Parser (String, Int)
occur w = do
    pUntil w
    string . pack $ w
    string "\t"
    n <- natural 
    string "\n"
    return (w, read n)


-- * Parse a natural number
natural :: Parser String
natural = many1' digit

-- * skip over all words in Text stream until the word we want
pUntil :: String -> Parser String 
pUntil = manyTill anyChar . lookAhead . string . pack
```

Comment: A parser is *not* the right tool for "find the first occurrence of x in a sequence of y". You should parse the entire string into a data structure which stores (key,value) pairs along with the position at which they occured. Your current problem is `t6` contains two key/value pairs (one in the entire string, one in a suffix) so naturally a backtracking parser finds both. Parsing each key unconditionally fixes this. With attoparsec, you are limited to getting the position as a byte index, but this should be sufficient for your purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach to consider:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative

import Data.Attoparsec.Text.Lazy
import Data.Attoparsec.Combinator
import Data.Text hiding (foldr)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as L (Text, pack)
import Data.Monoid

natural = many1' digit

-- manyTill anyChar (try $ char c <* eof)

pair0 w = do
  string (w <> "\t")
  n <- natural
  string "\n"
  return n

pair1 w = do
  manyTill anyChar (try $ string ("\n" <> w <> "\t"))
  n <- natural
  string "\n"
  return n

pair w = pair0 w <|> pair1 w

t1 = "hello\t999\nworld\t\900"
t2 = "world\t\900\nhello\t999\n"
t3 = "world world\t\900\nhello\t999\n"

-- * should fail
t4 = "world\t\900\nhello world\t999\n"
t5 = "hello world\t999\nworld\t\900"
t6 = "world hello\t999\nworld\t\900"

test t = parseTest (pair "hello") (L.pack t)

main = do
  test t1; test t2; test t3
  test t4; test t5; test t6
```

The idea is that `pair0` matches a pair with the given key at the beginning of the input and `pair1` matches the pair just after a newline.

The key is the use of `manyTill anyChar (try p)` which will keep skipping
characters until the parser `p` succeeds.

(btw - I learned about this use of `manyTill` and `try` by reading an answer written by @Cactus.)